# Adding a custom CakePHP Route

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

How can i configure a route connection to handle...

```
/users/{nameofuser_as_param}/{action}.json?limit_as_param=20&offset_as_param=20&order_as_param=created_at
```

in the routes.php file such that it calls my controller action like...

```
/users/{action}/{nameofuser_as_param}/{limit_as_param}/{offset_as_param}/{order_as_param}.json?
```

Note: Iam using Cakephp 2.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to handle...
>
> `/users/{nameofuser_as_param}/{action}.json`

That's pretty easy, and [in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

Assuming there is a call to [parseExtensions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions) in the route file, a route along the lines of this is required:

```
Router::connect(
    '/users/:username/:action',
    ['controller' => 'users'],
    [
        'pass' => ['username'],
        // 'username' => '[a-Z0-9]+' // optional param pattern
    ]
);
```

The pass key in the 3rd argument to `Router::connect` is used to specify which of the route parameters should be passed to the controller action. In this case the username will be passed.

For the rest of the requirements in the question it would make more sense for the action to simply [access the get arguments](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters). E.g.:

```
public function view($user) 
{
    $defaults = [
        'limit_as_param' => 0,
        'offset_as_param' => 0,
        'order_as_param' => ''
    ];

    $args = array_intersect_key($this->request->query, $defaults) + $defaults;
    ...
}
```

It is not possible, without probably significant changes or hacks, to make routes do anything with get arguments since at run time they are [only passed the path](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L612) to determine which is the matching route.

Comment: Thanks its working...but just a quick one.........what is the purpose of pass => "username"